# No module named sublime

Tags: python, sublimetext3, youtube-dl

I'm trying to work on some old code that used a library I'm not very familiar with anymore, and am getting the 'No module named' error. I'm using sublime text editor on windows. I had edited some things in build to run c++ previously if that might effect it.

If the library in particular matters, it is youtube_dl

I have tried `$pip install -upgrade youtube_dl` but it hasn't changed anything.

The code that is throwing an error is `import youtube_dl`

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific than that. At the very least, include the full stacktrace as well as the portion of your code that is causing the error.

Comment: Is your error message `No module named sublime` or `No module named youtube_dl`? Your post is very unclear. Please [edit] it and post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I searched around on the internet, and I found an answer.

(Edited for clarity)

*”Sublime is a module only available in Sublime Text embedded Python interpreters.
import sublime will only work from a plugin or inside the console, not on your system Python interpreter.”*

The forum post is [here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/no-module-named-sublime/5449).

Not sure if this will help, as I do not know if you are trying to import sublime, but this is literally all the info I could find.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: that does not help, unfortunately. Python is running fine through sublime for other programs, it seems that just the youtube_dl library is broken for me

Comment: are you running it through terminal?